# I have a strange output on my python code

Tags: python, output

i have a code that gives me a strange output. If i do print(winst) it gives the output 1234567891017, while the variable "winst" actually is 17, so where do the numbers 12345678910 come from? and how do i fix it?

```
N = int(input())
Waardes = []
for i in range(N):
Waardes.append(int(input(str(i + 1))))

Minimum = 100000000
Maximum = 0
Bezit = False
Winst = 0
for i in range(N):
if (Waardes[i] < Minimum):
    Minimum = Waardes[i]
    Bezit = True
elif (Waardes[i] > Maximum):
    Maximum = Waardes[i]
    if (Bezit):
        if (N > (i + 1)):

            if (not Waardes[i + 1] > Maximum):
                Winst = Winst + (Maximum - Minimum)
                Minimum = Maximum
                Maximum = 0
                Bezit = False
        else:
            Winst = Winst + (Maximum - Minimum)
            Minimum = Maximum
            Maximum = 0
            Bezit = False

print(Winst)
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it comes from this line:

```
Waardes.append(int(input(str(i + 1))))
```

I suppose it should be indented.

```
Help on built-in function input in module __builtin__:

input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

    Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

There's no need for the prompt.

```
N = int(input())
Waardes = []
for i in range(N):
    Waardes.append(int(input()))

Minimum = 100000000
Maximum = 0
Bezit = False
Winst = 0
for i in range(N):
  if (Waardes[i] < Minimum):
    Minimum = Waardes[i]
    Bezit = True
  elif (Waardes[i] > Maximum):
    Maximum = Waardes[i]
    if (Bezit):
        if (N > (i + 1)):

            if (not Waardes[i + 1] > Maximum):
                Winst = Winst + (Maximum - Minimum)
                Minimum = Maximum
                Maximum = 0
                Bezit = False
        else:
            Winst = Winst + (Maximum - Minimum)
            Minimum = Maximum
            Maximum = 0
            Bezit = False

print(Winst)
```

Comment: i'm actually very bad in python, this is a job for school. Can you please rewrite my code with your code you gave me .. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: I've added the code where the prompt is removed  and a couple of indents.  This doesn't mean the program is now OK, but since you say the result 17 was OK.  But with which input?   Veel geluk!  En lees dat artikel dat jdv doorgaf.